# How to get students whose 21th birthday is next month in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to obtain all students whose birthday is the next month (I've seen several answers to this) filtering only those who are going to be 21, any idea? My table name is `students` and the column name is `birthdate` (DATE), thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `birthdate`?

Comment: Showing some research and coding effort would make downvotes less likely.

Comment: Sorry @Mike, I've searched across answers but couldn't find any that could filter by "age", I also was wondering if TIMESTAMPDIFF() or date diffs would consider leap years to get the difference in years, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Your question shows no effort, only statements about your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the birthdate column is of a date type, you could use conditions like the following to filter out students who are 20 years old and have a birthday next month.

```
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE MONTH(birthdate) = (MONTH(NOW()) % 12) + 1
      AND
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW()) = 20
```

Comment: If the actual month is November then (MONTH(NOW()) + 1) % 12 would return 0

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles I guess that should be %13?

Comment: hmmm nope, cause if currently is December, then (12 + 1) % 13 = 0, not 1

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles Oh, didn't realise MONTH is 1 indexed. I suppose `(MONTH(NOW())) % 12 + 1` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If birthdate is of type date, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   students
WHERE
  birthdate BETWEEN
    LAST_DAY(CURDATE())+INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 21 YEAR AND
    LAST_DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE())+INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 21 YEAR
```

Comment: Nice and creative answer! Will try it

Comment: tnx, i didn't want to calculate manually the interval, i just wanted MySql to calculate it for me :) using BETWEEN it should be faster, and can also take advantage of an index on `birthdate` if it exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM students WHERE MONTH(birthdate)=(MONTH(CURDATE()) % 12 + 1)  AND
     (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(birthdate) = 21) ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94b31/1)

Comment: For December 'MONTH(CURDATE())+1' would return 13, it should consider Jan of the next year I suppose..

Comment: thanks! same as the comment to @Asad, if the actual month is November then '(MONTH(CURDATE())+1) % 12' would return 0..

Comment: it should be MONTH(CURDATE()) % 12 + 1 but also the year will not be calculated correctly